# How can I produce unicode symbols in a slack chat?

Tags: slack

How can I produce unicode symbols in a slack chat by typing their code?

As a mathematician, I routinely need to write things like ⨐∅⊋. In some systems I would just use some escape character and use (hex) `'0x2a10', '0x2205', '0x228b', '0x1f4a9'` or (decimal) `10768, 8709, 8843, 128169`.

But how can I do this in slack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about typing them in a way supported by your OS:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input#Hexadecimal_input

For example in **Linux** X11 system you can either (copying instructions from Wikipedia):

- Hold Ctrl+Shift and type u followed by the hex digits. Then release Ctrl+Shift.
- Press Ctrl+Shift+u, release, then type the hex digits, and press Enter (or Space or on some systems Shift or Ctrl).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/121288)

Comment: Updated information for Linux, I don't feel competent to write about other systems. Anyway, now I think there must be some stack exchange answer about typing unicode characters in general, just I couldn't find it.